# Upstart job doesn't die correctly

Tags: shutdown, upstart, reboot, services

I'm making a simple upstart daemon.

Following the Upstart documentation[1] I make the conf script:

```
description "Super Daemon" 
author "Bastian Baltasar Bux"

start on started dbus
stop on runlevel [06]

expect fork
exec /usr/bin/my-daemon
```

The script `/usr/bin/my-daemon` is a bash that call a python. The python script log information in a /var/log file. On that python script, I only make a `fork`. But when I check the forks like says in the Upstart doc [2], the method says that I do twice forks.

With that all, the start job is executed correctly, but the pid showed with the  `upstart my-daemon status` isn't the same that is in the log file. The error appears when I try to stop doing `status my-daemon stop`. That command doesn't end, I must to finish with Crtl-C.

I tried to change the `expect fork` to `expect daemon` but service stop doesn't ends neither.

When could be the problem?

[1] http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook

[2] http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#id158

Comment: How about `sudo stop my-daemon`?

Comment: Doesn't work, neither with `initctl stipo my-daemon`

Comment: Any useful info in /var/log/upstart/my-daemon.log? Why do you need a bash script to call Python script?

Comment: @schkovich thank for you question. Changing the line `exec /usr/bin/my-daemon` to `exec python $MY_SCRIPT_PATH` solve the issue. I think the problem is in the bash scritp that doesn't fork any time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I noticed you have already fixed the issue by fixing the `exec` line. For future readers, let's summarize the issue and the fix.

**Issue**: Running a forking python from a bash script from Upstart job does not get tracked correctly.

**Problem**: `expect fork` or `expect daemon` does not fix the issue.

**Solution**: Fix the script. Options:

- Switch from `exec /usr/bin/my-bash-wrapper` to directly calling python `exec python /path/to/script` (as demonstrated in comments above)
- Fix the bash script. Having a bash script with example contents of

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> python /path/to/script
> ```

has the issue of python getting executed separately from bash with a new process id. Thus it is ignored by Upstart as it is just a command parented by the Bash script. Adding `expect daemon` does not help as it is ignored in the first place.

Using bash script is possible the same way you fixed it in the Upstart script. Prefixing python call with `exec` makes the python run with same PID as the bash, which is tracked by Upstart. Then `expect fork` catches the fork() in the Python script, and Upstart is happily tracking the right process.

So, using a bash wrapper of:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> exec python /path/to/script
> ```

does the same thing.